# RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain (serverless)

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have been using serverless framework to create AWS - Node.js but I face issue

`RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain` . My step is

Step 1: `serverless`
Step 2: choose `AWS - Node.js - REST API`

Then I face this error `RequestError: self signed certificate in certificate chain`. What am I supposed to over this error ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from the node process running the `serverless` command. Likely caused by a firewall or system between yourself and the S3 bucket where these templates are stored.

You may try running `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 serverless`, which suppresses this error.